# Android using Splash Screen to load heavy Main data

Tags: android, asynchronous, optimization, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have a very heavy Main Acitivty class which the first time you install the app , freezes until all the data is loaded , I want to show my Splash Screen activity while all the data is loading in the Main Activity and show my activity ONLY when the Main Activity has loaded everything :

Here is my current splash screen activity , currently it only does this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "freezes until all the data is loaded" this sounds like some bad UX, maybe you should try to improve the experience by showing a loading or progress indicator instead of hiding the problem away behind a splash ? as a user, how do i know the app is doing anything ?

Comment: if you want to show a splash while you're loading everything, why not do the loading _in the splash activity_ ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody How can I load everything in the splash activity ?

Comment: by moving the code from your main activity to your splash activity :)

Comment: But ... how to initialize the elements from Main Acitivty from Another activity ? im confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comments on your question, it seems you're trying to update the UI of your MainActivity with the data you're loading. You can query/load your data on the splash activity, pass it on to the intent so you can gather it in onCreate of your MainActivity, or save all your data to SharedPreferences and access it from the MainActivity.

In SplashActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
// inside data loading completion callback or after synchronous data gathering methods
intent.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivity onCreate method

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String value = extras.getString("key");
```

You can pass models as json formatted strings if you need.

Answer (score 0):

if your splash screen named: spalsh.java
and your main activity named: MainActivity.java
first you create this class:

```
public class SliderPrefManager {
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private static final String Pref_Name="slider-pref";
private static final String Key_Start="startslider";
public SliderPrefManager(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Pref_Name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public Boolean startSlider(){
    return pref.getBoolean(Key_Start,true);
}
public void setStartSlider(Boolean start){
    pref.edit().putBoolean(Key_Start,start).apply();
}
```

}

and in your splash screen add this code:

```
sliderPrefManager = new SliderPrefManager(login_Activity.this);
            sliderPrefManager.setStartSlider(false);
```

and you checked boolean of view slash screen, add this code in your mainActivity:

```
if (sliderPrefManager.startSlider()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(choise_way_sec.this, login_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();

    }
```